# Differentiate between HTTP request and Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on ASP.NET WebApi and Angularjs

WebApi have a method

```
 [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SearchAddress(SearchDetails searchDetail)
        {
            //13.03993,80.231867
            try
            {
                if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
                    return response;
                }
                List<CollegeAddress> CollegeAddress = addressService.GetAddressFromDistance(17.380498, 78.4864948, 2000);
                HttpResponseMessage responseData = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, CollegeAddress);
                return responseData;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                return response;
            }
        }
```

And I have to call this method from client side.

When I call this method using `Ajax`, **it's not working, the method parameter `searchDetail` is always null if I use Ajax.**

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: rootUrl + '/api/Address/SearchAddress',
            async: false,
            data: searchDetail,
            type: "json",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            return response;

        }).error(function () {
            toastr.error('Somthing is wrong', 'Error');
        })
```

But when I call that method via `HTTP` request, **it is working.**

```
 $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: rootUrl + '/api/Address/SearchAddress',
            data: searchDetail,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            toastr.success('Account Created successfully!', 'Account Created');
            return response;
        }).error(function () {
            toastr.error('Somthing is wrong', 'Error');
        })
```

> **Why? What is the difference between them?  Why is Ajax not working and HTTP is?**

Comment: Im sure some1 will answer, ... but why do you use `$.ajax` mixed with Angular project? I would remove jQuery at all.

Comment: @MaximShoustin , Because http does not support `async:false` object. I want to call some method on synchronously. So i use Ajax for some time

Comment: I think it's server. If he do not configure to consume `application/json` you can't send such request. And http? It's by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's `ajax()` sends the data with Content-type: `x-www-form-urlencoded`.
Angular's `$http` sends the data with Content-type: `application/json`

Your server obviously expects JSON, but you set up the `$.ajax()` call incorrectly for that.

According to **[the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**:

- The `method` property doesn't seem to exist.
- The `type` property is supposed to determine the type of the request (e.g. 'GET', 'POST', etc.).
- In order to change the default content-type to `application/json` you can use the `contentType` property.

---

I have not tried it myself, but something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: rootUrl + '/api/Address/SearchAddress',
  async: false,
  data: searchDetail,
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Comment: `Angular's $http sends the data with Content-type: application/json` . It's okay. But it's not worked, if i have manually added the header in Ajax request.

Comment: Please, read my answer for the various problems in your code. You are using an invalid `type` value. This could for example force the default type which is `GET` etc.

Comment: If you want more info, you can open the DevTools -> Netword tab and capture the 2 requests. Then you can see what differences they have (in method, request URL, headers, content etc).

Comment: Okay +1 for that document, Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: rootUrl + '/api/Address/SearchAddress',
        async: false,
        data: searchDetail,
```

I assume that `searchDetail` is an object. This is what the docs say about the `data` property:

> ... It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.

So if the server expects JSON then you have to convert it to JSON first:

```
data: JSON.stringify(searchDetail),
```

And as @ExpertSystem has pointed out you have to change `method` to `type`.

Answer (score 0):

First you are duplicating the HttpPost, so just keep the second (and remove the namespace)
Second you want search detail to come from the body so decorate it with [FromBody]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SearchAddress([FromBody]SearchDetails searchDetail)
    {
```